# Class 'Stomp' not found

Tags: php, activemq-classic, stomp

I am using PHP 7.0 with Apache2 in Ubuntu trusty.

I have installed the STOMP library doing

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/stomp-2.0.0.tgz
pear install stomp-2.0.0.tgz
```

And adding extension=stomp.so to my php.ini.

With phpinfo() I can see the Stomp installed correctly:

[image]

But I have this script:

```
<?php

$foo = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
```

And When I run this error is shown:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Stomp' not found in
> /vagrant/www/web/activemq-server.php:3 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 {main}   thrown in /vagrant/www/web/activemq-server.php on line 3

**UPDATE:**

**This problem happens only when the script is run from console**. If the script is run from browser then it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the extension to php.ini for the CLI too ?
You can type " php -i | grep -i stomp " in the console to know if the extension is enabled

Comment: If I run that command, nothing appears. I did the extension to php.ini in this way: extension=stomp.so

Comment: I added the extension to this file /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini. As Melvyn said, it is necessary to added to Cli's php.ini, in my case localized in  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini.   Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the namespace.
$foo = new \Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');